# How do i open a fragment from an activity from the onClickListener of a recyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to open a fragment when an item in the recyclerView is clicked,in an Activity, then pass the text of the text view from the recycler view to the fragments text view.
the OnClickListener is in my adapter class. i cant find a mathcing solution for this in Kotlin.

`

```
class MyViewHolder(listView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(listView){
    var itemTitle : TextView

    var itemDetail: TextView


    init {
        itemTitle = listView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        itemDetail =listView.findViewById(R.id.description)

        listView.setOnClickListener {v: View ->
            var detailFragment: DetailFragment = DetailFragment()



        }

    }
}`
```

Comment: Do it in `onBindViewHolder()` method of Adapter class.

Comment: More details like whether the fragment is in the same Activity, whether the recyclerview is in a Fagment of the parent Activity are needed.

Comment: the recyclerView is in the parent activity, the fragment is not in the activity

Answer (score 0):

Do it in `onBindViewHolder()` method of Adapter class

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
     hoder.itemTitle.setText(your_data_list.get(position).getTitle())
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
         //open DetailsFragment with text right there.
     }
 }
```

Comment: please if you dont mind help with the code for the transaction in the activity and receiving the text passed at the fragments end